# sitemaps url encoding

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, sitemap, urlencode

What's the encoding I should use when generating site maps for google?
I'd like to have urls like:

```
example.com/supplì-rome
```

rather than:

```
example.com/suppl%C3%AC-rome
```

not sure whether [google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35653) requires the second form or not.
I'd like users to share nice links like in the first case.
I'm using Zend Framework router to handle nice links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google requires your Sitemap file to be **UTF-8** encoded and [**RFC-3986**](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc3986.html) valid.

Below is an example of a URL that uses a non-ASCII character (ü), as well as a character that requires entity escaping (&):

```
  http://www.example.com/ümlat.html&q=name
```

Below is that same URL, entity escaped:

```
  http://www.example.com/%C3%BCmlat.html&amp;q=name
```

Don't worry. Google will translate your URL's back to a human readable format within the search results. You can find additional information [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35653).

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, I should give google the link with %C3%B.. and in my site I can use a link like this: <a href='example.com/ümlat.html'> is it correct?

Comment: Yes, feel free to do so. Google will recognize them correctly. But as I said, they're not RFC-3986 valid. You should always use UTF-8 encoded URL's.